# Entity Framework Where query MVC application performance questions

Tags: performance, entity-framework, where-clause

I have websites table with the following data:

```
websiteID - int [Primary Key]
websiteName - nvarchar(128)
... (5 other columns)
```

On url, I have route with website name. At OnActionExecuting method I run:

```
public Website GetWebsiteByName(String wwwName)
{
    return _zEntity.Websites.Where(w => w.websiteName == wwwName).First();
}
```

to get website data. System can work with many websites on one database (requirement), but problem started on first.
When I do performance test with ANTS response time is 3 sec. Why does it take so long? How do I skip it?

Comment: How long does the query take if you run it from SSMS (assuming SQL Server)?

Comment: SSMS query execution shows 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the websiteName column, or query by websiteID instead.

Without an index, your queries will be slow.

Comment: I have an index on websiteName column.

Comment: Is websiteName the first field in your index?  Just having it as one of many fields in an index won't necessary help.

Comment: Is websiteName mapped as `nvarchar`? If EF is treating it as `varchar`, sql won't use the index.

Comment: AnnL websiteName is the only field in my index.

Comment: websiteName on model is declared as String:
public String websiteName { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Based just on the information you've provided, I'd suggest putting an index on the website name in your table.  That ought to speed things up.  But I'd consider matching on the website id instead of the website name:  matching on integers is simply faster than comparing 128-char strings.

Comment: Yes I know it. But in my opinion website name looks much better on url that id. I can shorten column length to 16 chars. I thought about solution to read all websites on ApplicationStart write it to application data but not as IEnumerable<Websites>, but add prefix to each website name i.e. "wi-" and than read exact data from application (not read them from db on each request). What do you think?

Comment: @MariuszGarsztka  Dean, above, makes a very good point.  Do you know how much time is taken up by the actual database query as opposed to the EF activity?  (And, actually, I don't know for sure that you're using EF.  Are you?)  If you want to cache the website objects (and I'd use the webcache rather than application state, but it's up to you), and access them by the website name, I'd use a dictionary object and use the website name as the key.  You might have to use a custom dictionary object since the built-in dictionary objects aren't serializable, but there are several out there.

Comment: Yes I'm using Entity Framework. Query on DB is rapid. I'd try to cache Website objects. Thank you for your suggestions. Do you know how to catch query created by EF to see what's wrong?

Comment: @MariuszGarsztka There are at least two ways: one is through use of SQL Profiler, and the other is through use of Jaroslaw Kowalski's [EF Tracing Provider] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx). This also apparently provides caching, which might also be of interest to you.